# Pattern Matching inside brackets with % sybol

Tags: java, regex

I am a newbie to Java and have been trying to pattern match some data inside a TD tag and brackets with a percentage symbol, but for the life of me cannot get it to work.

I am sure it is very simple and I Just want to extract the numbers before the % symbol in here :

```
<td>0 items (0%)</td>
```

I have tried quite a number of suggestions but none seem to work.

```
linecache = readercache.readLine();
System.out.println(linecache);
Pattern patterncf1 = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
tried
Pattern patterncf1 = Pattern.compile("<td>\\d+ \\w+ \\((\\d+)?%\\)</td>");
tried
Pattern patterncf1 = Pattern.compile("<td>\\((\\d+)?%\\)</td>");
tried
Pattern patterncf1 = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+)?%\\)");
```

but am always getting

```
<td>0 items (0%)</td>
```

Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

I also tried the suggestion below but still erroring out and I would assume that this is the right group in this case.

```
linecache = readercache.readLine();
System.out.println(linecache);
String pattern = "\\d+(?=%)";
Pattern patterncf1 = Pattern.compile(pattern) 
Matcher matchercf1 = patterncf1.matcher(linecache);
String passedvalue = matchercf1.group(1);
System.out.println(passedvalue);
```

This part in a different section of code works fine.

```
Pattern patternmb1 = Pattern.compile("<td>(.+?) GB</td>");
Matcher matchermb1 = patternmb1.matcher(line);
if (matchermb1.find()) {
    String passedvalue = matchermb1.group(1);
    String[] tmpStr = passedvalue.split("\\.") ; 
    String withoutDecStr = tmpStr[0]; 
    Float passedvalue2 = Float.valueOf(withoutDecStr);
    System.out.println("MIU: " + passedvalue2);
    JVMinusearray.add(passedvalue2);
```

I would appreciate if someone could offer some advice please.

Thanks

Comment: Please give a minimal example of the code that is failing. At least some of the patterns you posted do in fact match the input string.

Comment: try this one `\\d+(?=%)`

Comment: With your patterns, did you actually get the right group? It's {`pattern.matcher(somestring)`}`.group(1)`? for #2 and  #3 https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/capturing_groups.shtml

Comment: Yeah I believe so. I tried 1,2,3 in different cases. I also tried the above suggestion and still getting it. I must be doing something wrong as it should not be this hard. I have other patterns which match find just not this one.

Comment: @Paul check now i have edited my answer

Comment: @Paul if an answer really solves your question mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extract numbers before `%`, the following will  match

```
(\\d+(?=%))
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/aErEke/1)

Edit:

from your comment, i understood that the problem is in identifying the correct group to pick. in this regex, what you want in goup 1, you have to use group1 to make it work.

```
linecache = readercache.readLine();
System.out.println(linecache);
String pattern = "(\\d+(?=%))";  // just include ()
Pattern patterncf1 = Pattern.compile(pattern) 
Matcher matchercf1 = patterncf1.matcher(linecache);
String passedvalue = matchercf1.group(1);
System.out.println(passedvalue);
```

Comment: Thank you, but still no good. I am loosing hair by the second :). I added to my initial post showing what I did using this also. I did see the demo and that seems to work fine so currently no idea.

Comment: @Paul check now i have edited, you are using group 1. that why it is not working

Comment: @Paul if an answer really solves your question mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<td>.*\\((\\d+)%\\)</td>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<td>0 items (2000%)</td>");
if(matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

You will get the number appended to `%`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. It seems to work with a static string of text but not from the reading in of the data from the html file, so I will take this offline and see what's going on, but both suggestions have worked fine.

Thank you for your time. I appreciate it.

Regards,

Paul